# Prebid in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ads, prebid

has anyone managed to use prebid within a react-native project?

I need to handle many bidders, and cannot fin any way to do it as prebid.js uses window variable

Answer (score 0):

Though Prebid.js is written in JS, it must be used under web environment.

To use Prebid within a react-native project, you should checkout [prebid-mobile-react-native](https://github.com/devalentino/prebid-mobile-react-native) or official Prebid Mobile SDKs ([iOS](https://github.com/prebid/prebid-mobile-ios) / [Android](https://github.com/prebid/prebid-mobile-android))